# Pandas Rank Normalize Return Between -1 and 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The official documentation on pandas rank only provides the option to rank the column to percentages between 0 and 1, if `pct` is set to true.

```
DataFrame.rank(self, axis=0, method: str = 'average', numeric_only: Union[bool, NoneType] = None, na_option: str = 'keep', ascending: bool = True, pct: bool = False)
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to change the rank range to between -1 and 1.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything about rescaling the percentage range in the documentation for DataFrame.rank, but you are performing a linear rescaling. You want f(0) = -1, and f(1) = 1 so your linear function is f(x) = 2x - 1.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,10]})
x['pct_rank'] = x.rank(pct = True)
x['pct_rank_scaled'] = 2*x['pct_rank'] - 1

x
    a  pct_rank  pct_rank_scaled
0   1  0.166667        -0.666667
1   2  0.333333        -0.333333
2   3  0.500000         0.000000
3   4  0.666667         0.333333
4   5  0.833333         0.666667
5  10  1.000000         1.000000
```